# Count number of identical lines in two files using awk

Tags: awk, duplicates

I have a long series of files. Some of them have lines in common. I am trying to use awk to find the lines that are different between two files and then print that number to a variable for use outside of awk.

Here is what my awk code currently looks like:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$0;next}  {print  (!a[$1FS$2]?$0:"")}' C6H6_1651.com  C6H6_1652.com  | awk 'END { print NR }'
```

What I get out is `32` which is the number of lines in each of those files. I know from looking at those files that the desired output should be `2`, as there are only two lines that are different between the two files.

Other arrangements of these awk commands that I have tried are:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{!a[$1FS$2]?$0:"";next}  END { print NR }' C6H6_1651.com C6H6_1652.com
```

which outputs `64`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$0;next}  {print  (!a[$1FS$2]?$0:"")} END { printf NR }' C6H6_1651.com C6H6_1652.com
```

which outputs a line for every line in the document but the only lines that contain text are the ones that don't match between the two files. `64` then follows up this block of text.

Here are the contents of C6H6_1651.com

```
%chk=C6H6_1651.chk
%nproc=20
# mp2/cc-pVTZ

C6H6_1651

0 1
 C            0.000000000     1.394800000     0.000000000 
 C            0.000000000    -1.394800000     0.000000000 
 C            1.207900000     0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000     0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000    -0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C            1.207900000    -0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C            0.000000000     1.394800000     3.000000000 
 C            0.000000000    -1.394800000     3.000000000 
 C            1.207900000     0.697400000     3.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000     0.697400000     3.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000    -0.697400000     3.000000000 
 C            1.207900000    -0.697400000     3.000000000 
 H            0.000000000     2.482200000     0.000000000 
 H            2.149700000     1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000     1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000    -1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H            2.149700000    -1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H            0.000000000    -2.482200000     0.000000000 
 H            0.000000000     2.482200000     3.000000000 
 H            2.149700000     1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000     1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000    -1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H            2.149700000    -1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H            0.000000000    -2.482200000     3.000000000
```

Here are the contents of C6H6_1652.com

```
%chk=C6H6_1652.chk
%nproc=20
# mp2/cc-pVTZ

C6H6_1652

0 1
 C            0.000000000     1.394800000     0.000000000 
 C            0.000000000    -1.394800000     0.000000000 
 C            1.207900000     0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000     0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000    -0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C            1.207900000    -0.697400000     0.000000000 
 C            0.000000000     1.394800000     3.000000000 
 C            0.000000000    -1.394800000     3.000000000 
 C            1.207900000     0.697400000     3.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000     0.697400000     3.000000000 
 C           -1.207900000    -0.697400000     3.000000000 
 C            1.207900000    -0.697400000     3.000000000 
 H            0.000000000     2.482200000     0.000000000 
 H            2.149700000     1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000     1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000    -1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H            2.149700000    -1.241100000     0.000000000 
 H            0.000000000    -2.482200000     0.000000000 
 H            0.000000000     2.482200000     3.000000000 
 H            2.149700000     1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000     1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H           -2.149700000    -1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H            2.149700000    -1.241100000     3.000000000 
 H            0.000000000    -2.482200000     3.000000000
```

Comment: Here seeing samples of input and expected output will be important to help. So kindly add them in your question and let us know then

Comment: BTW, the second `awk` can be replaced with `wc -l`

Comment: @Barmar I was uncertain if I could take the output of the first awk (which should be ONLY the not matching lines) and then use ```wc -l``` to count them.

Comment: Although it seems like you could just increment an awk variable instead of printing the different lines.

Comment: Do you have to do this with `awk`? The `comm` command is designed for this.

Comment: `comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` will show all lines in file2 that aren't in file1.

Comment: @Barmar I don't have to use awk. It was the only thing I could find that I was even vaguely familiar with that people said could do this. I am completely self-taught for this. What does the ```-13``` mean in the ```comm``` command?

Comment: The title says you want to count the identical lines, but your code is counting the missing lines.

Comment: `comm` can print 3 columns: Lines unique to file 1, lines unique to file 2, and lines in common. The argument tells it which columns to omit, so `-13` means to omit the lines in file 1 and the common lines.

Comment: Use `man comm` to read the documentation.

Comment: Your subject says `Count number of identical lines` but your description says the opposite `find the lines that are different between two files and then print that number` - which do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to do this in awk try. Following will show lines which are present in both files.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
} 
($0 in array)
' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

OR to get number of lines in `awk` itself try:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
} 
($0 in array){
  count++
}
END{
  print "Total matching lines are:" count
}
' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

To know lines which are present in file1 and not in file2 try:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
} 
!($0 in array)
' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

OR

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
} 
!($0 in array){
  count++
}
END{
  print "Total lines found in file1 and NOT in file2 are:"count
}
' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

To get lines which are present in file2 and not in file1 try:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
} 
!($0 in array)
' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

OR

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  array[$0]
  next
} 
!($0 in array){
  count++
}
END{
  print "Total lines found in file2 and NOT in file1 are:"count
}
' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Above solutions(without `END` block one) will print lines in case you need to know only number of lines append `| wc -l` to above commands.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to output the count of common (or is it different?) lines so `($0 in array){cnt++} END{print cnt+0}'` for common and something else for different...

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you sir, I added comment in answer to get number of lines also since I written them on mobile difficult to rewrite them will edit them in morning sir